# Como evitar que javascript me pongan los decimales con el exponente "e"

Tags: javascript

Resulta que estoy programando muchas veces en mis programas y siempre me convierte los decimales con exponente e ejemplo yo pongo en la var

```
var Number = 0.00000007
```

Y me la convierte al siguiente formato

```
7e-8
```

Hay alguna manera posible de evitar esta conversion del formato para que mantenga tal como es los decimales. Las variables que me dan problemas son la letra i y las que les asigno decimales.

Basicamente me convierte los decimas a exponente cuando yo quiero mostrarlo solo con decimales.

El codigo de mi programa es.
https://pastebin.com/NVw9H5jL

Codigo.

```
// poner nombres a las variables
let espacio = '\n';
var Multiplicador = 2;
var losscount = 0;
let nadalkeios = '\n';
var cache = 0; var i; var cointobet; /* la que dan problemas con el exponente */




// con esto se si pierdo
function Pierdes(){

}

// Usar funciones
/*function checkWallet(startCoin){
  return 0.001
}*/

// elegimos 65 porcentaje
function incrementar(){
  coinToBet = coinToBet * 4;
  return coinToBet;
}

// normalmente es 50 porcentaje
/*
function incrementar(){
  coinToBet = coinToBet * 2.1;
  return coinToBet;
}
*/

function decrementar(){
    coinToBet = coinToBet / 2;
    return coinToBet;
}

// una funcion para saber lo que tenemos en el bolsillo
//startCoin = checkWallet(startCoin);

// imprime que llevas
// console.log(startCoin);

// empezamos definiendo los bet
// el bet empezara con 10
var coinToBet = 0.00000010;

function Win(){
    iimPlay("CODE:WAIT SECONDS=4")
    var result = window.content.document.getElementsByClassName("glyphicon-ok")[0].getAttribute('style');
    if(result=="")
    {
        return "Win";
    }else{
        return "Loose";
    }
        //alert(result);
}

var win = "";

// incrementar el bet
  //incrementar();
  //incrementar();
  //incrementar();
var i=0;
var wincount = 0;
var losscount = 0;
var x = 1.6;
var loose = 0;

function bid(){
        //implay
    iimPlay("CODE:WAIT SECONDS=4");

    let modifier = Math.floor(Math.random()*30 + 1);

    iimPlayCode("SET !ERRORIGNORE YES"
    + nadalkeios + "SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 60"
    + nadalkeios + "SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 10"
    + nadalkeios + "TAG POS=2 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=* CONTENT=" + coinToBet
                + nadalkeios + "WAIT SECONDS=0.2"
                + nadalkeios + "TAG POS=5 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=* CONTENT=" + modifier 
                + nadalkeios + "WAIT SECONDS=0.2"
                + nadalkeios + "EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR=\"HTML>BODY>DIV:nth-of-type(5)>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>DIV>BUTTON\" BUTTON=0"




)
}


function bid2(){
        //implay
    iimPlay("CODE:WAIT SECONDS=4");

    let modifier = Math.floor(Math.random()*30 + 1);

    iimPlayCode("SET !ERRORIGNORE YES"
    + nadalkeios + "SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 60"
    + nadalkeios + "SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 10"
    + nadalkeios + "TAG POS=2 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=* CONTENT=" + i
                + nadalkeios + "WAIT SECONDS=0.2"
                + nadalkeios + "TAG POS=5 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=* CONTENT=" + modifier 
                + nadalkeios + "WAIT SECONDS=0.2"
                + nadalkeios + "EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR=\"HTML>BODY>DIV:nth-of-type(5)>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>DIV>BUTTON\" BUTTON=0"




)
}


var contador = 0;
while(true){
  // el while esta limpio
  //
    bid();
    iimPlay("CODE:WAIT SECONDS=1");

    iimPlay("CODE:WAIT SECONDS=1");
    if(contador > 2){
        bid();
        var m = 0;

        while(true) {

            iimPlay("CODE:WAIT SECONDS=4");
            var resultt = window.content.document.getElementsByClassName("glyphicon-ok")[0].getAttribute('style');
            iimPlay("CODE:WAIT SECONDS=1");
            if(resultt == ""){
                bid();
                decrementar();
                if(loose>0){
                    break;
                    loose = 0;
                }
            }else{
                m++;
                loose = loose + 1;  
                if(m == 1){
                    i = 0.00000002;
                    bid2();

                }

                if (m == 2){
                    i = 0.00000002;
                    bid2();

                }

                if(m == 3){
                    i = 0.00000007;
                    bid2();

                }

                if(m == 4){
                    i = 0.00000010;
                    bid2();

                }

                if(m > 4){
                    x = x * 5;
                    i = 0.00000001;
                    bid2();

                }
            }
        }


        x = 1.6
    }




    //cache = 0;





  // decrementar el bet
  //decrementar();
  iimPlay("CODE:WAIT SECONDS=1");

  //si pierdo incremento, si gano decremento
  if(Win() == "Win"){
      contador++;
      wincount++;

      // a veces cuando gano puedo volver a ganar??

      if(wincount>4){
          decrementar();
          decrementar();
          coinToBet = 0.00000001;

          // hacer un loop en el momento que gano no hago nada cuando pierdo evaluo dos veces
          // agregar dos loops anidados.
          wincount = 0;
      }
      losscount = 0;
    decrementar();

  }else{
      contador = 0;
      losscount++;

      incrementar();


      //instrucc cuando pierdo multiplico porque ganar es mas probable
      if(losscount == 2){
         coinToBet = coinToBet * 3; 
      }

      if(losscount == 3){
          coinToBet = coinToBet * 3;
      }


  }

/*    if(losscount > 2){
          incrementar();
          incrementar();
          incrementar();
          incrementar();
          incrementar();incrementar();incrementar();
      }*/  



  //iimPlay("CODE:WAIT SECONDS=0.2")

  // apostamos la cantidad exacta
  //iimPlay("CODE:TAG POS=2 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=* CONTENT=" + coinToBet)


  // si el bet supera una cantidad paramos el programa
  if( coinToBet > 0.0000001){
        if(Win() == "Win"){
            iimPlay("CODE:WAIT SECONDS=2")
            coinToBet = 0.00000005;
        }
        if(losscount>3){
            iimPlay("CODE:WAIT SECONDS=2")
            coinToBet = 0.00000005;

        }
        // intentamos
        coinToBet = 0.0000005;

  }

  // si pierdo incremento

  // si gano mas de varias veces decremento

  // si pierdo muchas veces decremento


}


alert(contador);





/*if(losscount == 0){
        bid();

    }

    if(losscount == 1){
        bid2(0.1);

    }

    if(losscount == 2){
        bid2(0.4);

    }

    if(losscount == 3){
        bid2(1.6);

    }

    if(losscount > 4){

        bid2(x);
        x = x * 2;

    }*/

/*el loop
while(true){
              if(Win() == "Win"){

              }else{
                  var j=0;
                  while(true){
                      if(Win() == "Win"){
                            break;
                      }else{
                          if(j == 0){
                                bid();

                            }

                            if(j == 1){
                                bid2(0.1);

                            }

                            if(j == 2){
                                bid2(0.4);

                            }

                            if(j == 3){
                                bid2(1.6);

                            }

                            if(j > 4){

                                bid2(x);
                                x = x * 2;

                            }
                      }
                  }
                  break;
              }

          }*/



/*
// alerta termino el programa 
alert("termino");


iimPlay("CODE:WAIT SECONDS=1")

  // apostamos la cantidad exacta
  iimPlay("CODE:TAG POS=2 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=* CONTENT=" + coinToBet)

  // timer
  iimPlay("CODE:WAIT SECONDS=4")

  // bideamos
  iimPlay("CODE:EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR=\"HTML>BODY>DIV:nth-of-type(5)>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>DIV>BUTTON\" BUTTON=0")

*/
```

Comment: añade el código aquí por favor

Comment: Agregado! Lo puse mas claro

Comment: Aunque lo ponga como texto tambien me vale alguna manera de convertir para mantener formato?

Answer (score 2):

Entendiendo tu pregunta lo que deseas es ver los numeros sin notacion exponencial cientifica, lo que sugiero es usar el metodo de conversion toLocaleString() el cual te mostrara el valor completo y hasta con separacion de miles.

Aqui te envio un ejemplo del codigo.

```html
 <script type="text/javascript">
       // https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Number/toLocaleString

       var Number = 0.0000000123456;
       // var Number = 123456789987654321.8904;
       var Number = 12345678901234.1234;
       // 'es-es' para separacion de miles con puntos y decimales español 
       // 'en-en' para separacion de miles con comas y decimales en punto español
       // maximumSignificantDigits: 20  <- digitos significativos

       document.writeln(Number.toLocaleString('es-es', { maximumSignificantDigits: 20}));

       document.writeln('<br>');

       // SI NO DESEAS SEPARACION DE MILES USA este 'fullwide', {useGrouping:false} 
       document.writeln(Number.toLocaleString('fullwide', {useGrouping:false} ));
       
  </script>
```